# TDA2030 vs TDA2050 vs LM4440

Tags: amplifier, audio, integrated-circuit, sound

Which one of the three ICs you will suggest or most recommend to build an audio amplifier. I have checked the datasheets but still, I want to know how they perform in practice, which one sounds better and have the least noise.

All three ICs power rating is sufficient to power a 5W speaker but which one is best to drive 5W 8ohms speaker in terms of sound quality and noise?

Comment: Now you're just asking for opinions. What happened to the last question?

Comment: I already tried TDA2030 but not satisfied with the quality. I want to know is there a better option available?

Comment: Don't ask questions that solicit opinions and don't ask shopping questions and don't expect a speaker without an enclosure to produce any decent bass. Read the data sheets and work out which one has the least distortion because "sounding better" means one thing to one guy and a different thing to another AND it's application dependent. Voting to close on several issues that are unlikely to be resolved.

Comment: And don't delete questions that people have tried to help you clarify the issues on, just to ask the exact same thing without resolving the issues. You would be better off fixing what's wrong with the current project than trying other parts in the same faulty configuration.

Comment: Okay, don't be so rude. I am just a student and can make mistakes. I will try my best ✌

Comment: Vishal, people are merely asking you to follow the site rules which you have agreed to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions are "which one sounds better and have the least noise."

When your questions ought to be,
**How do I define these design specifications?** (so that I can make better design choices.)

Consider some metrics that may matter to you.

**Power:** Pk & RMS  This depends on the Impedance of the PSU, the output impedance of the Pwr Amp and the frequency response of the speakers, yet power does not define quality but they are related.  You need at least 50% more Pk power for headroom but distortion goes up as well as need for heat removal to prevent finger-burning temperatures and improve on reliability.

**THD:** Total Harmonic Distortion  Compare Specs at Power, load and frequency. Bass distortion demands much lower impedance regulated power sources.

**Noise:**  Since Power Amps normally have line level high signal to noise ratio, SNR signals at some high impedance input. (> 10k) but compare datasheet specs and beware that power supply noise can be the dominant source.

Other sources of Noise may be Intermodulation Distortion, IMD which is the nonlinear sum and difference frequencies that result from non-linearity.

### Your values may differ;

**THD:** 1% poor, 0.1% better, 0.01% best (for cheap amps)
**Noise:** -50 dB poor, -70 dB better, -90 dB best ( " " )
**PSRR:** PS rejection ratio 30 dB poor, 50 db good , 70 dB better
**Cost:** Your time, budget and all parts enclosed

You might also consider a higher grade Amp but still only us 5 ~ 10W.  e.g. LM1875

Comment: Vishal, you're still asking questions about the TDA2030 in a configuration that is supposed to deliver 20W. When you read the datasheet, you'll notice that it can't do that at 0.5% THD at all, and is barely able to at 10% THD. That is really the worst amplifier IC I've ever met.